# Laravel 5.0 file_put_contents error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Just moved laravel project on hosting and it says:

> production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message
>   'file_put_contents(/Users/max/sites/evocate.dev/storage/framework/sessions/7f7df88c52734c34a3f89286dc74d517d446c4fd):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in
>   /home/f/fb7929gh/evocate2/vendor/compiled.php:6440

Why it takes my local host path and where can I fix this?

Comment: Did you upload the vendor-folder to the new host or did you run `composer update/install` on the new server?

Comment: you should run a `composer dump-autoload` to clean all those references

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i've just uploaded vandor folder. It doesnt work?

Comment: Check the comment from @DamienPirsy - It seems like there are absolute paths stored in your /vendor/compile.php-file.

Answer (score 5):

This issue is due to the [Laravel Configuration Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#configuration-caching). You should typically run the

> php artisan config:cache

command as part of your production deployment routine. I suggest you

1. Remove the configuration cache file
2. Flush the application cache
3. Create a cache file for faster configuration loading

To do this, run the following Artisan commands on your command line

1. php artisan config:clear
2. php artisan cache:clear
3. php artisan config:cache

Where you don't have access to the command line on your server, you can [programmatically execute commands](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands) like this:

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return 'DONE'; //Return anything
});
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You should make sure this directory exists and you have valid file permissions to this directory

Answer (score 2):

Make a directory **`sessions`**  with proper permission inside **`storage/framework`**
You can make directory using terminal command in Ubuntu:

```
sudo mkdir storage/framework/sessions
```

Or you can create a directory directly inside **`project-root-folder/storage/framework/sessions`**

And also check `**storage**` and `**bootstrap**` have the full permission to write. `777` or `775`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be permission issue. please check if the director exist "storage/framework/sessions", if not you can create a session folder under framework directory.

Or please provide necessary write permission to storage folder for fixing the issue.